# changer function is not working working or error involved

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm kind fresh with Ajax and done some examples they worked, but then they stopped, I believe somewhere is error involved.

**mainfile**

```
<button class='chbt' title='Test' value=" . $i . " onclick='changer($(this).val())'></button>
```

changer function

```
function changer(val)
{
    if (val == null)
    {
        document.getElementById("dataedit").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } 
    else
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("dataedit").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","testing.php?id="+val,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**testing.php file**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$ged = $_GET['id'];
$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM review WHERE RID=".$ged);
$RRow=$query->fetch_array();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="scripts/jscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        alert("working123!!!");
        $('#dataformas').hide();
        $('#dataedit').show();
    </script>
        <form method='post' action='updatereview.php' id='updata' name='updata'>
        Vn<input name='rating' id='rating' type='range'  min='1' max='5' maxlength='500' value='<?php echo $RRow[4]; ?>' step='1' required />Pt<br><br>
        <textarea name='edittext' id='edittext' rows='5' cols='30'><?php echo $RRow[2]; ?></textarea>
        <span id='count2'></span>
        <script>
            //location.hash = ".updata";
            var el_t = document.getElementById('edittext');
            var length = el_t.getAttribute('maxlength');
            var el_c = document.getElementById('count2');
            el_c.innerHTML = length;
            el_t.onkeyup = function () 
            {
                document.getElementById('count2').innerHTML = (length - this.value.length)+' left';
            };
            </script><br>
                <input type='hidden' name='idas' id='idas' value="<?php echo $ged; ?>">
                <input type='hidden' name='cidas' id='cidas' value="<?php echo $RRow[3]; ?>">
                <button type='submit' form='updata' id='send_button' value='Submit'>Update</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I as you can see I need to pass one param which is integer generated by loop, so my changer function is not working and throws

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: where is id="dataedit"

Comment: `document.getElementById("dataedit").innerHTML = this.responseText;` <- It can't find the element with the id `dataedit`.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: you can't run jquery inside that ajax call.. it won't work... the ajax suppose to return server side json or something that you could work with on the client where "changer" response is

Comment: [code]<div class="dataedit" id="dataedit">
            </div>[/code] this is in the same file as changer();

Comment: UP... Anyone? Anyone?